# Why is the Italian term for Jews ebrei?

Tags: vocabulary

Isn't the analogy to ebrei Hebrews and not Jews, and is there an Italian analogy to the term Jews?

Does anybody know, how the change to the term ebrei came to be implemented?

Comment: Could you please add some more detail? What specific nuance of the difference between *Hebrew* and *Jew* in English are you trying to capture? Do you have an example sentence? For instance, Italians normally use *israeliano* to refer to the state and citizenship, and *ebreo* to refer to the religion (while the language is called *ebraico*); is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: What does *israeliano* even have to do with this topic? Most Jews in the world are not Israelis and many Israelis are not Jews.

Comment: @AaronSalz: This is already implied in the answers, but please note that, while in English “Hebrew” used as noun to mean a Jew is dated or offensive, in Italian it is quite exactly the other way around with *ebreo* and *giudeo*.

Comment: “change”? Which change? The term has always been ebreo, in Italian from Latin, in Latin from Ancient Greek, in Ancient Greek from, well, Hebrew: to quote the Treccani dictionary, *ebreo* derives from Latin *hebraeus*, which derives from late Ancient Greek *ἑβραῖος*, an adaptation of the Aramaic word corresponding to Hebrew *῾ibrī* (plural *῾ibrīm*), from the name of the alleged progenitor ῾Ēber, as already explained in egreg's answer.

Comment: Yes, but how come in Italy it is commonplace to use the term Hebrews, while in English and other languages the term Jews is the norm. When and how was this change implemented?

Comment: In Italy no one uses the term “Hebrews”, which is English: the Italian term is “ebreo” (plural, “ebrei”). Anyway, *there has never been any “change”*, as both I and egreg are trying to tell you. If anything, *other* languages have “changed”, using “Jew”, “Jude”, “juif” (and the Italian “giudeo”), which is somewhat inaccurate, since originally it refers to just *one* of the tribes of Israel, the one descended from Judah, one of the sons of Jacob.

Comment: @DaG I am pretty sure, there was a change. The current Jews are the descendants of the inhabitants of Judea and Samaria, hence the name in referrence to Judea.

Answer (score 11):

The term Jew has the correspondent *Giudeo* (from *Giuda*, that is, Judah).

It's not used very often, nowadays. It was in the past: *Giudecca* was a common name of Hebrew neighborhoods in cities of Southern Italy and Sicily (see https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giudecca_(quartiere_ebraico)). It's debated whether the Giudecca islands in Venice have the same origin.

The generic term *ebreo* comes, according to the [Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/ebreo),

> dal latino *hebraeus*, greco tardo ἑβραῖος, adattamento della voce aramaica corrispondente all’ebraico ῾ibrī (plurale ῾ibrīm), dal nome del supposto capostipite ῾Ēber
>
> from Latin *hebraeus*, late Greek ἑβραῖος, adaptation of the Aramaic term corresponding to Hebrew ῾ibrī (plurale ῾ibrīm), from the name of the alleged founder ῾Ēber

Of course the origin is the same as the English *Hebrew*.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is also giudèo, which is cognate with the English word "Jew". However, this word is less commonly used; it can indicate specifically members of the tribe of Judah, and may have anti-semitic connotations in some contexts.

Source: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/giudeo/